# How to append data to each row of csv file without overwriting old content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file whose each row contains comma separated elements:

```
abc,233,345,400
```

I want to append new data to each row of the csv file, but that instead of comma separated, the appended columns should be space separated after the first appended element.

For instance, if I am to append the list [12, 13, 14] to the above row, then it should look like:

```
abc,233,345,400,12 13 14
```

However, I am stuck at the following:

```
with open(csv_dir, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    list = [12,13,14]
    for i in reader:
        i += list
```

Now, if I append the list to the row and then write it back to the file, the whole row would be over-written as comma separated. Is there any way out?

Comment: *Is there any way out?* - yes, to read/write directly without reader/writer

Comment: The number of rows is far too large. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileinput`, it's not exact what you want but it works:

```
import fileinput


for line in fileinput.input(filein, inplace=True):
    line = line + "," + " ".join(list) + "\n"
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Tried running, but it somehow converts my csv file into a blank one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Read the csv with the function [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) (where you can explicitly use the ',' separator or any other), and write the csv with the [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) funtion. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

def function_to_generate_new_column_values(row):
    return [12,13,14]

df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=',')
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, function_to_generate_new_column_values(x))), axis=1)
df.to_csv('file2.csv', sep = ',', header = True, mode = 'w', index=False)
```

You can add the list to each row by editing the function "function_to_generate_new_column_values" on the code above.

Comment: What is `str` in `df.apply()` ?

Comment: str = string (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html). It is used in map (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). function_to_generate_new_column_values returns a list of integers. For each of these elements, you are calling str(item in list), which gives you a list of string elements. This is necessary in the str.join function (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), which expects a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are performing a single element append, not an extend like you actually want.

Here is an example of something that should work given your data and example.  I added a csv_outdir value for the output file to do a row by row write.

```
with open(csv_dir, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    with open(csv_outdir, 'w+', newline='') as outf:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(outf, delimiter=',')
        list = [12, 13, 14]
        for i in reader:
            i.extend(list)
            writer.writerow(i)
```

Comment: But this simply appends the list elements as comma separated in the new file, which I don't want.